# How to load a csv in Java

Tags: java, csv

I have a .csv file that I want to load in Java so that afterwards I will be able to work on it as on a normal matrix (array). Here you can see my code:

```
package MirMir;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Try1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Madalin/NetBeansProjects/imp fr/src/com/mkyong/util/Tracker.csv"));
        scanner.useDelimiter(",");
        while (scanner.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.print(scanner.next() + "|");
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

The program runs perfectly without any errors, just the output I get in the end is: "BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)" and that's all, without any data or anything.

Comment: can you show sample content of your cvs file ?

Comment: It seems you are mixing Ant or Maven building your application and running your application. Are you using an IDE?

Comment: two lines of your csv may work a miracle in terms of getting an answer.

Comment: Hey! Thank yout for your help. Here is a sample of my .csv file https://mirmir.sharefile.com/app/#home/myfiles

Comment: I think the other link is not the right one. Here is another one: https://mirmir.sharefile.com/d-s0601fbd47a442289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way for this

```
public class Tracker {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        File f =new File("D:/Tracker.csv");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String s ;
        while ((s=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Well this might work ;)

*P.S. Change the file location*

Answer (score 0):

**The code is fine. No problem. I tested it on a sample csv file.**

*There seems to be some problem with your csv file.*

Post a sample from your csv.

Comment: Hey!Thank you for your help. Here is a link with my .csv file https://mirmir.sharefile.com/app/#home/myfiles

Comment: Sorry. In case the other link does not open, here is a better one: https://mirmir.sharefile.com/d-s0601fbd47a442289

Comment: Hey    @MirMir


CSV file means that data should be separated by comma ',' and not semicolon.

Or use

scanner.useDelimiter(";"); in your code

Comment: Hey. Thx for your help...but still it does not work. If I eventually find out the error I will post it.